# JSTL tags within struts tag

Tags: jsp, struts, jstl, struts-tags

Im trying to use 2 different functions for onChange event as follows:

```
<html:select  property="distributionCategoryCode" tabindex="5"   onchange="<c:choose><c:when test="${model.editT == true}">enableTextboxDirect('${model.dtxtrmks}');</c:when><c:otherwise>enableTextboxDirect();</c:otherwise></c:choose>" >
```

But getting JSP error as follows:

Expecting quoted value, got character: =
Attribute: ${model.editTaxes is not a valid attribute name
Expecting quoted value, got character: t

Any inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't arbitrarily nest JSP tags like that, it's not legal JSP (or XML).

You need to set the value separately.

In this case I barely see a reason to special-case it in the rendered output, instead pass two parameters to `enableTextboxDirect`. I don't see a usecase for doing it any other way.

```
<html:select property="distributionCategoryCode"
             onchange="enableTextboxDirect(${model.editT}, '${model.dtxtrmks}')>
```

Even if you had to write a one-liner JS wrapper in case you cannot modify `enableTextboxDirect` it's *still* a better solution than bothering to change the entire attribute.

Comment: @ dave...option of sending a 2nd parameter is my 1st choice but I didnt want to change the exisiting function as it is used in many places in the application. So want to know if JSTL can accompalish....

Comment: @JNPW That's why I suggested a JS wrapper around it. Yes, by setting a new JSTL-accessible variable, which is what I suggested first. Just drop the appropriate JS string in the attribute.